# error C2664: show_info: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [20]' to 'char

Tags: c++, c2664

I have a small structure:

```
struct price
{
    char name[20];
    char shop[20];
    int pr;
    price *next;
};
```

A function that doesn't work:

```
void show_info(price *&head, char cur)
{
    bool found = 0;
    price *temp = new price;
    temp->name = cur;
    for (price *i=head; i!=NULL; i=i->next)
        if (temp == i)
        {
            cout<< i->shop << i->pr;
            found = 1;
        }
        if (!found)
            cout << "The the good with such name is not found";
        delete temp;
 }
```

A main file:

```
int main()
{
    price *price_list=NULL;
    char inf[20];
    list_fill(price_list);
    cout << "Info about goods: ";
    show_list(price_list); //there is no problem
    cout <<"Input goods name you want to know about: ";
    cin >> inf;
    cout << "The info about good " << inf << show_info(price_list,inf)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I need to fix my function so it can work properly.

As stated the error is c2664.

Comment: Is it `show_info()` or `show_list()`?

Comment: erm... yes its show_info(). my mistake.

Comment: It might be worth replacing `char[20]` by `std::string`. I see that you are trying to implement some kind of search; by using `std::string` you can avoid trouble.

Comment: @Grafit Copy and paste my function.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the function the following way

```
#include <cstring>

//...

void show_info( const price *head, const char *cur )
{
    bool found = false;
    const price *i = head;

    for ( ; i != NULL && !found; i = i->next )
    {
        found = strcmp( i->name, cur ) == 0;
    }

    if ( found )
    {
        cout<< i->shop << i->pr;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The the good with such name is not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: we make `const price *head` and `const char *cur` to make `strcmp` work?

Comment: @Grafit The function will work without these qualifiers. They simply means that neither the list nor the string will be changed inside the function. Also you may use string literals as the second argument.

Comment: this function looks better. but the project still doesnt work. @vlad

Comment: @Grafit It means that you use the function incorrectly. It seems you are trying to assign its return value to some object.

Answer (score 1):

```
void show_list(price *&head, char cur)
```

should be

```
void show_list(price *&head, char cur[] )
```

as you're passing `inf` i.e. `char [20]` at `show_info(price_list,inf)`

PS: There *might* be other problems too

Comment: true. now there are 2 errors. error c2440 : =: cannot convert from 'char []' to 'char [20]'

Comment: @Grafit Well try to analyze those errors, they won't be too hard for this simple code, if you're _really_ lost come back at SO with new post

Comment: @Grafit for new error I believe its coming from `temp->name = cur;`. Use strcpy to copy string `strcpy(temp->name , cur );`